# rxjs, forkJoin(array).mergeMap(...), inner mergeMap never get called

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

In my case there are multiple requests could be performed in parallel at first, after those requests complete, another request will be sent with previous result, the pseudo code would look like

```
let uploads$ = [obs1$, obs2$, obs3$];
Observable.forkJoin(uploads$).mergeMap(
  res => {
    // never get called if uploads$ = []
    let data = someCalculation(res);
    return this.http.post('http://endpoint/api/resource', data);
  }
).subscribe(
  res => {
  }
);
```

If `uploads$ = []`, the inner mergeMap never got called.

Can someone help? I'm on RxJS 5.4

Comment: You can simple have an `if` condition that checks if `uploads$` is empty and if it is you won't use `forkJoin` and directly subscribe to `this.http.post`.

Comment: hi @martin, your idea is a solution, I'm still wondering that we cannot mergeMap with a forkJoin, but forkJoin returns Observable indeed

Comment: The problem is that `forkJoin` emits when all its source observables emit at least one item and all of them complete. Since `uploads$` is empty `forkJoin` will never have anything to emit. You could also prepend a dummy observable `let uploads$ = [Observable.of(null), obs1$, ...];` and then just ignore it but this seems lame (this would guarantee there's at least one observable every time).

Comment: A dummy `Observable.of(null)` can keep my code a little bit simple, thanks @martin, saved my time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not called b/c there is no emission on the source observable. To create one on, if observables is empty you can use the `defaultIfEmpty` or `toArray` operators.

```
const observables = [];
Rx.Observable.forkJoin(observables)
  .defaultIfEmpty([]) // or .toArray()
  .mergeMap(results => Rx.Observable.of(results.length))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Awesome! This is correct and more elegant solution, thanks!